# How to open markers popups on leaflet via external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

Considering a custom floor plan been showed with leaflet with markers loaded from a geojson file. Each of the markers have a related page and those pages have hyperlinks aiming to the map. I would like to add #id to those hyperlinks.

If for example, the map url was domain.com/map, the "Marker 1" page (domain.com/marker-1) would have a link (domain.com/map#maker-1) that would open the map with the actual marker for "marker 1" on the center of the map with it's popup open.

My question is how do I open the map with a certain marker on the center and with it popups open when I add a hash to the url (domain.com/map#maker-1)?

Here goes my code:

index.php

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.css" /> 
    <script src="geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
</body>
```

geojson.js

```
var groupsGeoJson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features":[
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-120,60]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "<h1>Maker 1</h1>"
            },
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-80,40]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "popupContent": "<h1>Maker 2</h1>"
            },
            "id": 2
        }
    ]
};
```

map.js

```
var mapMinZoom = 2;
var mapMaxZoom = 6;
var mapIniZoom = 2;
var mapCenterLat = 20;
var mapCenterLng = -75;

var groupsIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'images/silver_coin.gif',
  iconSize: [32, 32],
  iconAnchor: [16, 32],
  popupAnchor: [0, -28]
});

var baseLayer = new L.TileLayer('layers/baseLayer/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {           
    minZoom: mapMinZoom, 
    maxZoom: mapMaxZoom,
    noWrap: true
}); 

var groups= L.geoJson(groupsGeoJson, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {icon: groupsIcon});
  }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});

var map = new L.Map('map', {
  layers: [baseLayer, groups],
  center: new L.LatLng(mapCenterLat, mapCenterLng),
  zoom: mapIniZoom     
});

var southWest = map.unproject([0, 16384], map.getMaxZoom());
var northEast = map.unproject([16384, 0], map.getMaxZoom());  
var mapBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest,northEast);    

map.setMaxBounds(mapBounds);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  var popupContent = "<p>Test</p>"
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
  }
  layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}
```

Comment: I like to point out that I'm not using Drupal and also that the hyperlink isn't on the same url as the map.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just pass the parameters (coordinates, content...) for that marker (or the id if you have a database) and then just center the map on that point, draw the marker and open the popup?